# How do I get rid of the warning in this simple recursive implementation of BST

Tags: c++, class, recursion, binary-search-tree, function-definition

I am trying to implement DSs in C++, here is a simple implementation of a Binary Search Tree Class with insert and search functions. The code compiles and gives the output as required.
Someone at codereview pointed out that the search function gives a warning and the code in the search function is broken. The warning is similar to  'not all control paths have a return statement' but I thought that is how a recursive function would look like. Is the warning a problem and how do I get rid of it? Also, how is the code broken? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class BstNode{
int data;
BstNode* left;
BstNode* right;

public:
BstNode(int data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}
~BstNode();

void Insert(int data)
{
    if(this->data >= data)
    {
        if (this->left == NULL)
            this->left = new BstNode(data);
        else 
            this->left->Insert(data);
    }
    else
    {
        if (this->right == NULL)
            this->right = new BstNode(data);
        else 
            this->right->Insert(data);
    }
}

bool Search(int data)
{
    if(this->data == data)
        return true;
    else if(this->data >= data)
    {
        if(this->left == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            this->left->Search(data);
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->right == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            this->right->Search(data);
    }

}
};

int main()
{
BstNode* ptr_root = new BstNode(15);
ptr_root->Insert(10);
ptr_root->Insert(16);
int num;
std::cout<<"Enter the number: \n";
std::cin>> num;
if (ptr_root->Search(num))
    std::cout<<"Found\n";
else
    std::cout<<"Not Found\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->left->Search(data);` -> `return this->left->Search(data);`. A `return` only terminates the *current* function invocation. If a function is called recursively, it still only terminates one invocation at a time.

Comment: Got it, thanks HolyBlackCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function Search returns nothing in these paths

```
    else
        this->left->Search(data);
```

and

```
    else
        this->right->Search(data);
```

You have to write

```
    else
        return this->left->Search(data);
```

and

```
    else
        return this->right->Search(data);
```

The function can be defined with a single return statement the following way

```
bool Search( int data ) const
{
    return ( this->data == data ) || 
           ( this->data >= data ? this->left  && this->left->Search( data )
                                : this->right && this->right->Search( data ) );    
}
```

Actually the condition

```
this->data >= data
```

may be substituted for

```
this->data > data
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad, I got that there needs to be return for all the paths. But what would happen if the code is like the original one in my post? It still gives the correct output for search.

Comment: @Nothing_8484 There is undefined behavior. It seems it works because the result is returned in the same register.